# canActivate and canDeactivate don't work together

Tags: angular, angular6

(Angular 6) My problem:

- Route **A** has canDeactivate, when I try to go to Route **B** I need to confirm.
- Route **B** has canActivate and I dont have authority to access.
- Then redirect to Route **C** but in this moment canDeactivate from Route **A** asks again for confirmation.

How to skip this second confirmation?

```
export interface PendingChangesComponent {
canDeactivate: () => boolean | Observable<boolean>;
}

@Injectable()
export class PendingChangesGuard implements 
CanDeactivate<PendingChangesComponent>, OnInit, OnChanges {

constructor(private confirmationservice: ConfirmationService,
    private translate: TranslateService) {
    console.log('construtor d');
}

ngOnInit() {
    console.log('init d');
}

ngOnChanges() {
    console.log('on changes d');
}

canDeactivate(component: PendingChangesComponent): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    debugger

    if (component.canDeactivate()) {
        return true;
    }
    return Observable.create((observer: Observer<boolean>) => {
        this.confirmationservice.confirm({
            message: this.translate.instant('can.deactivate'),
            accept: () => {
                observer.next(true);
                observer.complete();
            },
            reject: () => {
                observer.next(false);
                observer.complete();
            }
        });
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return true in `canDeactivate() component method` when you need to navigate to C... You can set a specific component field and set that to be true like this:

```
// everything inside the A component


canDeactivate():boolean {
   return this.allowRedirect || yourOtherConditions;
}

// ... right before you need to navigate to C
this.allowRedirect = true;
this.router.navigate(["routeC"]);
```